# Facebook php sdk query based on field value

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a web app to integrate with facebook using the facebook php sdk.

I am able to request and see a list of events my user has, however I would like to limit that list to only those where the is_viewer_admin == true.

Basically I only want to see the events the user has created or is the admin of.

```
$fb = Facebook::get('/me/events?fields=name,is_viewer_admin,start_time');
```

is there a way to specify that within the fields query?

Comment: The Graph API currently doesn't have much filtering abilities. As FQL is deprecated, I guess your only option is to filter the response programmatically.